# Network discovery in Java using multicasting

Tags: java, networking, discovery

I'm trying to make a client/server Java App. Both client and server will be running on the same wi-fi network. Server will be running on a specific port that client is aware of.

I am planning to send a multicast message from client through the network for that specific port to discover the server. However, I'm not too sure how I can find out which IP in my network received my message.

Do I need to create a socket on the client and listen to incoming packets once I send my multicast message in case server replies back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(1)server listens on a pre-arranged port

```
DatagramSocket s = new DatagramSocket(8888);
s.receive  //(1)
s.send     //(2)
```

(3)client sends a message to the port, on the broadcast IP, 255.255.255.255

```
DatagramSocket c = new DatagramSocket();
c.send(255.255.255.255:8888,msg)     //(3)
c.receive  //(4)
```

the client binds to a port too. we didn't specify it, so it's random chosen for us.

(3) will broadcast the message to all local machines, server at (1) receives message, with the client IP:port.

(2) server sends response message to client IP:port

(4) client gets the reponse message from server.

Comment: I'm using OpenJDK 6 and your send call seems pretty far from what I'll have to do. Still, you kind of gave just enough to get me on the right track and that's pretty swell.

Comment: Server doesn't get client's send. See code here: https://gist.github.com/kilaka/5799444

Comment: The server did receive a response only after changing the client, by replacing 255.255.255.255 with the server's ip address. Why didn't 255.255.255.255 work?

Comment: The following worked great, with MulticastSocket: https://gist.github.com/kilaka/5799664

Answer (score 8):

I would strongly recommend using [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/). It has a lot of features and it will do all the UDP stuff. JBoss uses it for their clustering.

Comment: I only need multicasting just to find my server on the network. Once both sides know about each other, they will communicate through UDP datagrams. 

JGroups seems to have way more features than what I need, but since I haven't been able to find anything else, I will try to use it. 

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try using **`java.net.MulticastSocket`** (available since Java 1.1). If you don't need the rich feature sets of libs like [jgroups](http://jgroups.org), [hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com) etc. that plain Java API might serve you well enough.

See also example pages [here](http://staff.www.ltu.se/~peppar/java/multicast_example/) and [here](http://web.nchu.edu.tw/~jlu/cyut/multicast.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [SSDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol).  It's what UPnP devices use to discover each other.  It's multicast on port 1900 and just uses really simple packets to send around IPs and service information.

[Cling](http://teleal.org/projects/cling) is a UPnP lib you can pull from.  Note I'm not recommending you move to UPnP - just the discovery protocol used.